# Solution of Dimensionless Partial Differential Equation Over a Semi-Circular Domain

Tags: differential-equations

My problem is to solve the following BVP.

[image]

and I want to recreate a contour plot like the following graph using Mathematica.

[image]

I am trying with the following code.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
k = 5;
α = 3.0*π/4.0;
η = 0;
pde = Laplacian[u[r, θ], {r, θ}, "Polar"] == 
   k^2*u[r, θ];
bc = u[1, θ] == 
   1 - (1 - η)*HeavisideTheta[θ - α];
sol = NDSolveValue[{pde, bc}, u, {r, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, Pi}]
ContourPlot[sol[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
  Contours -> 50, ColorFunction -> "Pastel", AspectRatio -> Automatic,
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

But the code is continuously running without showing any result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Another approach**:

When dealing with numerical solvers, discontinuities from functions like `HeavisideTheta` can introduce major hurdles. Such discontinuities might result in convergence issues or even failures in securing a solution. A typical method to mitigate this is to "smooth out" the discontinuity, allowing the numerical solver to work more effectively.

The logistic function (or sigmoid function) is one such tool to achieve this smoothing:

$$f(\theta)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-a (\theta -\alpha )}}$$

Here:

- $\alpha$ is the point of discontinuity.
- $a$ controls the "sharpness" of the transition.

For a large value of $a$, the logistic function closely approximates a step function, making it a suitable choice for this purpose. The advantage of the logistic function is that it transitions smoothly from $0$ to $1$, thereby avoiding the abrupt change that can confound numerical methods.

By using the logistic function, we create a gentle transition around the point of discontinuity, allowing the numerical solver to handle the problem more robustly and often leading to better solutions. The sharpness of this transition can be adjusted by varying $a$, but care should be taken: making the transition too sharp (by choosing a very high value for $a$) might reintroduce numerical issues.

Based on this approach, let's apply the logistic function to smooth out the discontinuity in your differential equation. Here's the solution implemented using a logistic function instead of a piecewise function:

```
k = 5;
α = 3*π/4;
η = 0;
a = 50;  (*Controls the sharpness of the transition*)

(*Logistic function to smooth the discontinuity*)
smoothStep[θ_, α_, a_] := 1/(1 + Exp[-a (θ - α)]);

pde = Laplacian[u[r, θ], {r, θ}, "Polar"] == k^2*u[r, θ];

bc = u[1, θ] == 1 - (1 - η)*smoothStep[θ, α, a];

sol = NDSolveValue[{pde, bc}, u, {r, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, Pi}];

ContourPlot[sol[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], Mod[ArcTan[x, y], Pi]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> "Pastel", AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
PlotLegends -> Automatic, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotPoints -> 75]
```

[image]

I hope you find it useful!

Comment: Thank you for enriching myself.

Answer (score 6):

Replacing `HeavisideTheta` with `Piecewise` makes it work. it could be a limitation of NDSolve. I do not know.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
k=5;
α=3*π/4
η=0;
pde=Laplacian[u[r,θ],{r,θ},"Polar"]==k^2*u[r,θ];
bc=u[1,θ]==1-(1-η)*Piecewise[{{0,θ<α},{1,True}}]
sol=NDSolveValue[{pde,bc},u,{r,0,1},{θ,0,Pi}]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[sol[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
  Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> "Pastel", AspectRatio -> Automatic,
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Note that `HeavisideTheta` can be written using `Piecewise`

```
Plot[1 - (1 - η)*   HeavisideTheta[θ - α], {θ, -4, 4}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[1 - (1 - η)*   Piecewise[{{0, θ < α}, {1, True}}], {θ, -4,   4}]
```

[image]

> How to remove the black dots that appears on the boundary of the
> semicircle?

Just add more `PlotPoints`:

```
ContourPlot[sol[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
  Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> "Pastel", AspectRatio -> Automatic,
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
 PlotPoints -> 75]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### This below shows the problem more clearly

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
k = 5;
α = 3*π/4;
η = 0;
pde = Laplacian[u[r, θ], {r, θ}, "Polar"] == 0;
bc = u[1, θ] == 1 - (1 - η)*HeavisideTheta[θ - α];
sol = DSolveValue[{pde, bc}, u[r, θ], {r, θ}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we do the same thing, but using `NDSolve` instead of `DSovle` and get an error

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
k = 5;
α = 3*π/4;
η = 0;
pde = Laplacian[u[r, θ], {r, θ}, "Polar"] == 0;
bc = u[1, θ] == 1 - (1 - η)*HeavisideTheta[θ - α];
sol = NDSolveValue[{pde, bc}, u[r, θ], {r, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Changing to `Piecewise` fixes the above.

Maybe this is a bug or could be a feature.

Comment: Thank you very much. How to remove the black dots that appears on the boundary of the semicircle?

Comment: @user94537 updated

Comment: Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: It's sufficient to replace `HeavysideTheta` by `Unitstep`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I see. This looks also like a good workaround. Easier than `Piecewise`. I did not try it, but I believe you :)

Comment: Please help me for the next part if possible.  (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/290825/solution-and-plot-of-coupled-partial-differential-equation-over-a-semi-circular)