# Solution and Plot of Coupled Partial Differential Equation Over a Semi-Circular Domain.II

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, finite-element-method

This question is connected with reference to my previous question ([Solution of Dimensionless Partial Differential Equation Over a Semi-Circular Domain](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/290671/solution-of-dimensionless-partial-differential-equation-over-a-semi-circular-dom)), where I asked for a help to solve the following BVP.
[image]

I would like to thank Nasser (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/70/nasser) for his kind help with the following code.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
k=5;
\[Alpha]=3*\[Pi]/4;
\[Eta]=0;
pde=Laplacian[u[r,\[Theta]],{r,\[Theta]},"Polar"]==k^2*u[r,\[Theta]];
bc=u[1,\[Theta]]==1-(1-\[Eta])*Piecewise[{{0,\[Theta]<\[Alpha]},{1,True}}]
sol=NDSolveValue[{pde,bc},u,{r,0,1},{\[Theta],0,Pi}]
ContourPlot[sol[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
  Contours -> 30, ColorFunction -> "LakeColors", AspectRatio -> Automatic,
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
 PlotPoints -> 100,ContourStyle->None]
```

Now I have the following BVP which uses the solution of first one.
[image]

I am trying proceed using the following code.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
k=5;
\[Alpha]=3*\[Pi]/4;
\[Eta]=0;
L=1;
pde1=Laplacian[s[r,\[Theta]],{r,\[Theta]},"Polar"]==k^2*s[r,\[Theta]];
bc1=s[1,\[Theta]]==1-(1-\[Eta])*Piecewise[{{0,\[Theta]<\[Alpha]},{1,True}}];
sol1=NDSolveValue[{pde1,bc1},s,{r,0,1},{\[Theta],0,Pi}]
pde2=Laplacian[u[r,\[Theta]],{r,\[Theta]},"Polar"]==-(4.0*L)-(k^2*s[r,\[Theta]]/.sol1);
bc2=u[1,\[Theta]]==0;
sol2=NDSolveValue[{pde2,bc2},u,{r,0,1},{\[Theta],0,Pi}]
ContourPlot[sol2[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
  Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> "LakeColors", AspectRatio -> Automatic,
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
 PlotPoints -> 75,ContourStyle->None]
```

But it shows some errors. How should I proceed correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you used `NDSolveValue` to solve the first PDE, then you can use that solution in the second PDE using `sol1[r,θ]` and not as you had it `s[r,θ]/.sol1`

I also took the chance to change `Piecewise` to `UnitStep` as suggested in comment by UlrichNeumann on your earlier question. It seems simpler than using `Piecewise` as I did before. `UnitStep` does not cause same problem with NDSolve as `HeavisideTheta` did.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
k = 5;
α = 3*π/4;
η = 0;
L = 1;
pde1 = Laplacian[s[r, θ], {r, θ}, "Polar"] == k^2*s[r, θ];
bc1 = s[1, θ] == 1 - (1 - η)*UnitStep[θ - α];
sol1 = NDSolveValue[{pde1, bc1}, s, {r, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, Pi}];
pde2 = Laplacian[u[r, θ], {r, θ}, "Polar"] == -4*L - k^2*sol1[r, θ];
bc2 = u[1, θ] == 0;
sol2 = NDSolveValue[{pde2, bc2}, u, {r, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ContourPlot[
 sol2[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> "LakeColors", 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotPoints -> 75, ContourStyle -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.