# Post Processing of Solution and Plot of Coupled Partial Differential Equation Over a Semi-Circular Domain

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, finite-element-method

Linked Question: [Solution and Plot of Coupled Partial Differential Equation Over a Semi-Circular Domain.II](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/290825/solution-and-plot-of-coupled-partial-differential-equation-over-a-semi-circular/290826#290826)

Many many thanks to @Nasser (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/70/nasser) for his kind help to understand different aspects of `Mathematica` associated with this problem.

I have the following BVP.
[image]

Also I have following BVP that uses the solution of first one.

[image]

Code is given below.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
k = 5;
\[Alpha] = 3*\[Pi]/4;
\[Eta] = -1;
L = 1;
pde1 = Laplacian[s[r, \[Theta]], {r, \[Theta]}, "Polar"] == 
   k^2*s[r, \[Theta]];
bc1 = s[1, \[Theta]] == 1 - (1 - \[Eta])*UnitStep[\[Theta] - \[Alpha]];
sol1 = NDSolveValue[{pde1, bc1}, s, {r, 0, 1}, {\[Theta], 0, Pi}];
pde2 = Laplacian[u[r, \[Theta]], {r, \[Theta]}, "Polar"] == -4*L - 
    k^2*sol1[r, \[Theta]];
bc2 = u[1, \[Theta]] == 0;
sol2 = NDSolveValue[{pde2, bc2}, u, {r, 0, 1}, {\[Theta], 0, Pi}]
```

Now I have to perform the following integral

[image]

and have to plot the same as a function of the parameter `K` for different values of the parameter `\alpha` to regenerate a figure as follows:

[image]

How to proceed the same using `NIntegrate` function of `Mathematica`?

Comment: Are you sure the plot is for `sol1[Sqrt[x^2], 0]` ? I do not get same plot. You might want to check the paper. Here is the [code](https://12000.org/tmp/09272023/notebook.nb)  and screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICYE0.png)

Comment: Yes. I checked the paper. However I also have the same doubt because during contour plot of s we have seen only positive variations of s. Then it is not possible to get negative variations of s. However I have one more part associated with the integration. Could you please guide me on that if possible?

Comment: You can't integrate from 0 to 2 Pi over theta, since your domain is only from 0 to Pi. Are you sure the integration is from 0 to 2 Pi ?

Comment: That was my typing mistake. I have edited the question. Could you please answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't get the same exact plot for the second part. This is what I get

This is the code. Feel free to change it as needed.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
η = -1;
L = 1;
pde1 = Laplacian[s[r, θ], {r, θ}, "Polar"] == k^2*s[r, θ];
bc1 = s[1, θ] == 1 - (1 - η)*UnitStep[θ - α];
solS = ParametricNDSolveValue[{pde1, bc1}, s, {r, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, Pi}, {k, α}];
pde2=Laplacian[u[r,θ],{r,θ},"Polar"]==-4*L-k^2*solS[k,α][r,θ];
bc2 = u[1, θ] == 0;
solU = ParametricNDSolveValue[{pde2, bc2}, u, {r, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, Pi}, {k, α}];
```

Now generate two plots, one for Pi/4 and one for 3 Pi/4

```
data1 = Table[{k, 2/Pi*NIntegrate[ 
      solU[k, Pi/4][r, θ], {r, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, Pi}]}, {k, 0, 100, 1}];

data2 = Table[{k, 2/Pi*NIntegrate[ solU[k, 3*Pi/4][r, θ], {r, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, 
       Pi}]}, {k, 0, 100, 1}];
```

Now plot them

```
ListLinePlot[{data1, data2}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> {"alpha=Pi/4", "alpha=3 Pi/4"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You see, it is a little higher than what you showed. They meet at `1.5` on the y axis, while paper shows them meeting at `0.5` at y axis.

Comment: Thank you. Actually there was one another constant quantity which I have not included for simplicity. Your result is fine. I have modified accordingly. Thank you so much for your time and kind help on this.